# Where can I learn assembly?

Tags: programming, microprocessor, assembly

I am a student and didn’t find any proper video even on YouTube for this.
So, Where can I learn Assembly Language Programming for the 8085 Microprocessor?

It would be very helpful if someone would provide free videos for the same as, I urgently need to learn it for my exams.

Note: I already have basic knowledge of the Instruction Set.

Comment: You could start by not inventing unnecessary TLAs. In any case, this question is far too broad. What do you already know about assembly language programming in general?

Comment: I assume YT is YouTube. I bet there is something there the problem is finding something useful for your level of understanding of microprocessor architecture and previous exposure to assembly language. One problem I have run into is videos with a presenter other than a native English speaker. Sometimes just changing the video speed can make a big difference especially for people from India who seem to speak much faster than I can follow in YouTube videos.

Comment: This is not a genuine question. It's a kid who wants to learn assembly programming by watching TV. That's insane. To top it off you refer to your exam, which is completely irrelevant for this websites which focuses on _quality answers_. Hence the downvotes.

Comment: Either way, the core problem with this question is that you are asking for a recommendation of a resource, which is off-topic.

Comment: A video is rarely the right place to learn technical things.  You usually need good books.  A video taped lecture (where you have the referenced books) may be a good thing.  Some video by a random youtuber is unlikely to be of use.  Find a good book on the 8085, and work your way through it - and actually do the examples on hardware and solve (and check) any tasks that the book gives you.

Comment: @JRE found ONE link but was not useful. You are supposedly correct..

Comment: Microprocessors and Interfacing: Programming and Hardware by Douglas V Hall

Comment: You can't find a better book anyway....its followed by generations for basics...

Comment: @MITURAJ Sir hamare hsc level (textbook) ke beyond hai thats why.. anyway thank you very much...

Answer (score 4):

1. Read instruction set description carefully.

   Read assembler documentation carefully.

   Write some code.

   Figure out why it didn't work.

   Go back to step 1, 2, or 3, depending on what you messed up.

Note that the above doesn't include watching videos.  There is no substitute for simply doing it.  After a project or two, you might actually get good at it.